# Assign mouse buttons for Spotify

Tags: mouse, spotify, xbindkeys

I recently started using Ubuntu. On my Windows (I use a dualboot), I have an application called Xmouse control (or something along those lines) I use it to assign my mouse buttons to Spotify (skip a song, prev, play/pause,..) I've searched online for an alternative, but I just can't get it to work in `xbindkeys`. Can anyone help me out on the syntax for the config file?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for mouse commands cab be found here:
 https://blog.hanschen.org/2009/10/13/mouse-shortcuts-with-xbindkeys/